# ffplay won't play internal(embedded) subtitle?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, .srt

I want to play videos with their embedded subtitles, which is possible using VLC or even my smart TV. Both recognize the subtitle and play(show) it.

Since ffplay is my favorite player, I want to do the same thing via ffplay, but I didn't make it. I can play external subtitles using `-vf "subtitles=filename.srt"`, but no chance to play internal subtitle. It looks like not detected by ffplay, but ffprobe shows the subtitle stream information.

Anyone knows how it's done?

Thank you guys

Comment: I don't believe ffplay has support for 608/708 captions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter like your example in your question but point to the same input file:

```
ffplay -vf subtitles=input.mkv input.mkv
```

If you want to choose a different subtitle stream then use the `stream_index` option. This example will choose the third subtitle stream:

```
ffplay -vf subtitles=input.mkv:stream_index=2 input.mkv
```

Or use `mpv` player and press `j` or use `--sub=1` option.

Comment: This works, but something is wrong.  The video window opens late(about 5~6 seconds), and it kills the disk I/O and CPU!  In fact, The problem is with every seek of video(arrow keys), ffplay copy the entire video file somewhere and causes lag in playing(5 seconds).

Comment: @mohammads Maybe a bug. I don't know. Consider making a [bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/). But I don't know of a better method at the moment. Or use `mpv` instead. It's a lot like `ffplay` and supports FFmpeg filters.